# How to restore postgresql data without backup file?

Tags: sql, django, database, postgresql, backup

I've deleted database tables from django shell by accident. I am using postgresql database. Is there a way to get at least some of the data back?

Comment: upvote cause I've been here

Comment: @VaoTsun I have restaurants table and all entries of it were deleted an hour ago.

Comment: the db is local? or some aws or heroku or smth else?..

Comment: @VaoTsun It is on the remote server but not in aws or heroku.

Comment: so then you don't even accidentally have a backup...

Comment: @VaoTsun No, I don't have a backup.

Comment: what you can try to get from a disk in this case is more about FS and quilting - It's out of SO scope I think